# Configure unicorn service script using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, unicorn

In my `/etc/init.d/unicorn` startup script I have the hard-coded paths as follows:

```
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-dev
export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-dev:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-dev/gems:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-dev@global/gems

DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-dev/bin/unicorn

UNICORN_OPTS="-D -c /home/unicorn/unicorn.conf -E production"
```

I am using RVM and when I change the ruby version, then the current ruby should be used for unicorn.

### Question 1

So how can I make sure that these variables always point to the proper ruby?

### Question 2

In my bundle I am using rack 1.5.5. Now on my production server I had to install the `unicorn` gem as a "stand-alone-gem" so that I can start my server using:

```
service unicorn start
```

Now the `unicorn` gem installed `rack 1.6.x` and now my Rails app crashed because rack is already loaded. Now locally I would just execute it with `bundle` but how can I do that when I am using this `/etc/inid.d` script.

The part where the server is started looks like follows, and I don't know how I could "inject" the bundler call there or if that is a good practise at all:

```
# ...

log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" $NAME || true
if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- $UNICORN_OPTS; then
```

The config: `/home/unicorn/unicorn.conf`

```
listen "127.0.0.1:8080"
worker_processes 2
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/myapp"
pid "/home/unicorn/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"
```

Comment: Internal reference `reciplets#59`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rubyuser` has all these `rvm` and `rubies` installed, one might parse the output of `rvm info`, running the latter from this user:

```
`sudo -H -u rubyuser bash -c '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && rvm info | grep "^ \+GEM_"| sed -e "s/^ \+/export /" -e "s/: \+/=/"'`
```

The command above will *set* the variables `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH`. To just output them, remove backticks around this command.

For rvm installed in local, it’s even simpler:

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" && rvm info | grep "^ \+GEM_"| sed -e "s/^ \+/export /" -e "s/: \+/=/"

# export GEM_HOME="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1"
# export GEM_PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global"
```